Incorrect generation of enum from yaml by SpringCodegen
I added to my yaml file new "Scheme" enum:
SchemeEnum:
type: string
  enum:
    - SCHEME_I
    - SCHEME_II

after generation is finished in generated public enum SchemeEnum I have enums like:
I("SCHEME_I"),
II("SCHEME_II");

I would like to stay with
SCHEME_I("SCHEME_I"),
SCHEME_II("SCHEME_II");

I do not know whay SpringCodegen doing this. When I add one more value, like :
SchemeEnum:
  type: string
  enum:
    - SCHEME
    - SCHEME_I
    - SCHEME_II

everything is correct, I am getting
public enum SchemeEnum{
   SCHEME("SCHEME"),
   SCHEME_I("SCHEME_I"),
   SCHEME_II("SCHEME_II");

in my generated class. Is there any way to fix it? Should I change something in configuration?
I am expecting to get generated class like this:
public enum SchemeEnum{
  SCHEME_I("SCHEME_I"),
  SCHEME_II("SCHEME_II");


The below yml is generating correct class structure
SchemeEnum:
  type: string
  enum:
    - SCHEME_I 
    - SCHEME_II 
    - SCHEME_III
  x-enum-varnames:
    - SCHEME_I 
    - SCHEME_II 
    - SCHEME_III

with below dependencies and plugin
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.19</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>order-inbound</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>
                            ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/grocery-app-v1.json
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <modelPackage>com.dev.model.generated</modelPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <Library>spring-boot</Library>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Thx man, it works :)
